# Why am i getting "relation does not exist" when it does?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, populate

I'm getting an error while attempting to populate my table with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO d_table
SELECT category.name, film_category.film_id
FROM category
INNER JOIN film_category.film_id ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
```

It returns an error

> "relation film_category.film_id does not exist"

These are the tables in the database:

```
**category**
category_id
name         


**film_category**
film_id
category_id
```

Need both fields in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your INNER JOIN doesn't appear to be correct. You aren't specifying a relation, but a column. I think you wanted

```
INSERT INTO d_table
    SELECT
        category.name, film_category.film_id
    FROM category
    INNER JOIN film_category
    ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. I was under the impression I could use a column for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have relation `film_category` in your from clause